# knockout.js - nested array data and cascading pre-populated dropdown lists binding

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, cascadingdropdown

I'm fairly new to knockout.js, however, I've been happily using it in my ASP.NET MVC 4 project, until I ran into this obstacle which has been bothering me for a while, can't seem to put my finger on it.

The scenario which I'm working on requires several combinations of location data (region, country, city), i.e. cascading dropdown lists, which isn't a problem to do when inputting fresh data, but I ran into problem(s) when trying to edit the saved data.

Data is in JSON format, with nested arrays, looks like this (shortened for illustration purposes):

```
var newData = 
[
  {
    "ID":1,
    "Name":"Australia and New Zealand",
    "Countries":[
      {
        "ID":13,
        "Name":"Australia",
        "Cities":[
          {
            "ID":19,
            "Name":"Brisbane"
          },
          {
            "ID":28,
            "Name":"Cairns"
          },
...
```

I suspect I can't load the data (or more clearly, to **bind** it) properly since I'm having trouble accessing the Region sub-array (which contains Region's Countries) and the Countries sub-array (which contains Countries' Cities).

Then there's the matter of having prepopulated options, which works partially, the viewmodel loads the number of lines, but doesn't select anything.

Here's the VM:

```
   var existingRows = [
    {
        "Region": 1,
        "Country": 13,
        "City": 19
    },
    {
        "Region": 1,
        "Country": 158,
        "City": 3
    }];

   var Location = function (region, country, city) {
       var self = this;
       self.region = ko.observable(region);
       self.country = ko.observable(country);
       self.city = ko.observable(city);

       // Whenever the region changes, reset the country selection
       self.region.subscribe(function () {
           self.country(undefined);
       });

       // Whenever the country changes, reset the city selection
       self.country.subscribe(function () {
           self.city(undefined);
       });
   };

   var LocationViewModel = function (data) {
       var self = this;

       self.lines = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function (row)
       {
           var rowRegion = ko.utils.arrayFirst(newData, function (region)
           {
               return region.ID == row.Region;
           });
           var rowCountry = ko.utils.arrayFirst(rowRegion.Countries, function (country) {
               return country.ID == row.Country;
           });
           var rowCity = ko.utils.arrayFirst(rowCountry.Cities, function (city) {
           return city.ID == row.City;
           });
           return new Location(rowRegion, rowCountry, rowCity);
       }));

       // Operations
       self.addLine = function () {
           self.lines.push(new Location())
       };
       self.removeLine = function (line) {
           self.lines.remove(line)
       };
   };

   var lvm = new LocationViewModel(existingRows);

   $(function () {
       ko.applyBindings(lvm);
   });
```

HTML code:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: lines">
    <tr>
        <td><select data-bind="options: newData, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'ID', optionsCaption: 'Select a region...', attr: { name: 'SubRegionIndex' + '['+$index()+']' }, value: region"></select></td>
        <td><select data-bind="options: Countries, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'ID', optionsCaption: 'Select a country...', attr: { name: 'CountryIndex' + '['+$index()+']' }, value: country"></select></td>
        <td><select data-bind="options: Cities, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'ID', optionsCaption: 'Select a city...', attr: { name: 'CityIndex' + '['+$index()+']' }, value: city"></select></td>
        <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $parent.removeLine'>Remove</a></td>
    </tr>    
</tbody>
```

I tried to modify the Cart editor example from the knockout.js website with prepopulated data, but haven't really made much progress, I seem to be missing something. Didn't really find anything with nested arrays so I'm stuck here...

I've put up the full code on JSFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/fgXA2/1/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the way in which you are binding to the selected item in your select lists:

```
<select data-bind="
    options: newData, 
    optionsText: 'Name', 
    optionsValue: 'ID', 
    value: region">
</select>
```

Here you are binding the `ID` property from your JSON data to the `region` property on your view model.

This means that when you bind your second select list:

```
<td data-bind="with: region">
    <select data-bind="
        options: Countries, 
        optionsText: 'Name', 
        optionsValue: 'ID', 
        value: $parent.country">
    </select>
</td>
```

You attempt to bind to `region.Countries`. However, `region` simply contains the selected region `ID`. In this case the console is your friend:

> Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError:
>   Countries is not defined;

The same problem is true of your third select list for Cities since you are now attempting to bind to `country.Cities` where `country` is also just the `ID`.

There are two options available here. The first is to remove the `optionsValue` parameters, thus binding the *actual* JSON objects to your view model properties. That and a binding error on your Cities select box (you were binding to `CityName` instead of `Name`) were the only problems:

http://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/wHtRZ/

As you can see from the example I've used the `ko.toJSON` utility to output your view model's object graph. This can be very useful in resolving problems (in your case you would have seen that the `region` property was just an number).

The downside of the above approach is that you end up storing a copy of all of the countries, and their cities for the selected country in your view model.

A better solution if dealing with large data sets would be to only store the selected identifier (which I believe you were attempting to do originally) and then define computed properties that filter your single data set for the required values.

An example of this can be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/benfosterdev/Bbbt3, using the following computed properties:

```
    var getById = function (items, id) {
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(items, function (item) {
            return item.ID === id;
        });
    };

    this.countries = ko.computed(function () {
        var region = getById(this.selectedRegion.regions, this.selectedRegion());
        return region ? ko.utils.arrayMap(region.Countries, function (item) {
            return {
                ID: item.ID,
                Name: item.Name
            };
        }) : [];
    }, this);

    this.cities = ko.computed(function () {
        var region = getById(this.selectedRegion.regions, this.selectedRegion());
        if (region) {
            var country = getById(region.Countries, this.selectedCountry());
            if (country) {
                return country.Cities;
            }
        }

    }, this);
```

You can see from the rendered object graph that only the currently selected countries and cities are copied to the view model.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, and the debug pointers! Really appreciate it. Just a follow-up question - as I'm submitting the form to the server, I've relied on the optionsValue, so I guess I would have to use your second suggestion as the best option available?

Comment: Answering my own question - I've followed your second suggestion and extended it with the Add/Remove lines option. Works great. Thanks for the inspiration :)

Comment: If you are sending your data to the server using a normal form submission then yes you would need to set the `optionsValue` parameter. Alternatively you could use your view model to submit the data in which case you have complete control over what you send.