# Knockout computed function not updating when value changed in binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've built a cascading dropdown with Knockout, but the cascading part (`ko.computed`) is not updating.

Knockout version is `3.0.0`.

Preface:

I'm using a tree data structure to model the cascading.

```
{ id: '', text: '', childItems: [] }
```

Idea taken from:

[knockout.js - nested array data and cascading pre-populated dropdown lists binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491591/knockout-js-nested-array-data-and-cascading-pre-populated-dropdown-lists-bindi)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GWVW8/)

Html:

```
<select data-bind="options: manufacturers,
                   optionsCaption:'Manufacturer',
                   optionsText: 'text',
                   optionsValue: 'id',
                   value: selectedManufacturer">
</select>
<select data-bind="options: models,
                   optionsCaption:'Model',
                   optionsText: 'text',
                   optionsValue: 'id',
                   value: selectedModel,
                   enable: enableModels">
</select>
<select data-bind="options: engines,
                   optionsCaption:'Engine',
                   optionsText: 'text',
                   optionsValue: 'id',
                   value: selectedEngine,
                   enable: enableEngines">
</select>
```

JS:

ViewModel:

```
function ViewModel(items) {
    this.manufacturers = ko.observableArray(items);
    // These three observables should be numbers (e.g. 1)
    // Corresponding to the id
    this.selectedManufacturer = ko.observable();
    this.selectedModel = ko.observable();
    this.selectedEngine = ko.observable();

    function getById(items, id) {
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(items, function(item) {
            return item.id === id;
        });
    }

    this.models = ko.computed(function(){
        var items = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(this.manufacturers);
        var id = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(this.selectedManufacturer);
        return id ? getById(items, id).childItems : [];
    }, this);

    this.enableModels = ko.computed(function(){
        var items = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(this.manufacturers);
        var id = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(this.selectedManufacturer);
        return id ? getById(items, id).value > 0 : false;
    }, this);

    // generate engines based on models
    this.engines = ko.computed(function(){
        var items = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(this.models);
        var id = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(this.selectedModel);
        return id ? getById(items, id).childItems : [];
    }, this);

    this.enableEngines = ko.computed(function(){
        var items = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(this.models);
        var id = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(this.selectedModel);
        return id ? getById(items, id).value > 0 : false;
    }, this);
}
```

Data:

```
var items = [
    { text: 'Ford', id: 1, childItems:
     [
         { text: 'F-150', id: 1, childitems:
          [
              { text: 'Gasoline', id: 1, childitems: [] },
              { text: 'Diesel', id: 2, childitems: [] }
          ]
         },
         { text: 'F-250', id: 2, childitems:
          [
              { text: 'Gasoline', id: 3, childitems: [] },
              { text: 'Diesel', id: 4, childitems: [] }
          ]
         }
     ]
    },
    { text: 'Honda', id: 2, childItems:
     [
         { text: 'Civic', id: 5, childitems:
          [
              { text: 'Gasoline', id: 5, childitems: [] },
              { text: 'Electric', id: 6, childitems: [] }
          ]
         },
         { text: 'Accord', id: 6, childitems:
          [
              { text: 'Gasoline', id: 7, childitems: [] },
              { text: 'Electric', id: 8, childitems: [] }
          ]
         }
     ]
    }
];
```

Binding:

```
var module = {};

module.viewModel = new ViewModel(items);

ko.applyBindings(module.viewModel);
```

Update:

Here is the [complete working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/GWVW8/2/) based on the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that in your "enable" computeds, you are returning the `value` property of item that is found.  You would likely want to check if `childItems` exists and then if `childItems` has a length that is greater than 0.

Otherwise, you could remove the "enable" computeds, and just bind against the length of the options like `enable: models().length` (will be falsey if 0 length and truthy if greater than 0).

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/GWVW8/1/

There were also some typos (`childItems` vs. `childitems`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I indeed needed a second set of eyes.